# Setting up a UIbutton in Objective C in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am a novice so bear with me :)

I am following this tutorial [socket Iphone app tutorial](http://bitcows.com/?p=249)

The tutorial is on using an iPhone app to control the GPIO pins on a Raspberry Pi. In the tutorial they use a Segment Control. I want to use a UIButton instead and make the button act as a momentary switch. However, when I set up the code to use a UIButton I get a "Use of Undeclared Identifier 'holdDown'" Error see code below. The code I got in response to my poorly written question orginally.

```
UIButton *valveToggle = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[valveToggle addTarget:self action:@selector(holdDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[valveToggle addTarget:[[self action:@selector(holdRelease) forControlEvents:];
 UIControlEventTouchUpInside;
- (void) holdDown
{
    NSLog(@"hold Down");
    //Set GPIO High
}

- (void)holdRelease
{
    NSLog(@"hold release");
    //Set GPIO Low
}}
```

I feel as though I am missing a declaration in my header file? Here is what my header file looks like

```
// //  ViewController.h //  RocketOne // //  Created by Christopher        Beck on 8/9/2559 BE. //  Copyright © 2559 BE Christopher Beck. All rights      reserved. //

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<NSStreamDelegate> {
 }

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSInputStream *inputStream;
@property  (nonatomic, retain) NSOutputStream *outputStream;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *valveToggle;
@property (weak, nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *logo;

- (IBAction)ToggleValve:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)shutdown:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)reboot:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender;



@end
```

valveToggle is the name of my Button.

Just to be clear I am trying to get rid of the "Use of Undeclared Identifier 'holdDown'" Error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using UIButton.

```
  UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(holdDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
  [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(holdRelease) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  - (void)holdDown
  {
     NSLog(@"hold Down");
     //Set GPIO High
  }

  - (void)holdRelease
  {
      NSLog(@"hold release");
     //Set GPIO Low
  }
```

Comment: Do I need to import any library for holddown to not get "use of undeclared identifier 'holdDown' error?